# How to retrieve messages relative to a WHOLE skype conversation from SQLite main.db (query)?

Tags: sqlite, skype

I downloaded the "DB_Browser for SQLite" and I can see all the content of the database, but now i don't know how to show (for example) a full conversation between two contacts. I know that there exists Skyperious to do that easely but I want to know how to formulate the query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found myself ))

```
select author, datetime(timestamp, 'unixepoch', 'localtime'), body_xml from messages where dialog_partner="?????NAMEOFPARTNER?????";
```

Comment: Nice job. Thank you for sharing. If you can mark your own answer as accepted, it'll be helpful in putting a closure to the question.

Comment: in 2 days says the "system" ))

Comment: and makes us to become slaves of machine also )